# how to find a file

Tags: linux

I am using linux server and a file is missing and I need to find all the files matching a name MyMissingFile ...how can I issue a command that will do a recrusive search of all the directories under user folder and tell me where the file is
I am not a root user.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
 cd <userfolder>
 find . -name <filename> -print
```

BTW, filename could be contain a pattern, and

Thus

```
 find . -name '*MyMissingFile*' -print
```

Comment: `-print` is unnecessary (it's the default)

Comment: `cd` is unnecessary: `find /path/to/dir -name filename`

Comment: worth mentioning `-iname` when used the search is NOT case sensitive

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to find a file.

The easiest one is probably to use the `locate` command. This command uses a cache of known files. In order to use it, you need to make sure the cache is up-to-date, using `updatedb`. In your case, you will have to trust that it is up-to-date since you are not root and cannot update the db. To use `locate`, type:

```
$ locate MyMissingFile
```

If you want only files called exactly "MyMissingFile", use:

```
$ locate MyMissingFile | grep "/MyMissingFile$"
```

Now if you know in which directory your file is, you can use `find`. `find` does not rely on a cache db, and will scan recursively the directory and print all the files it finds. There are tons of options to filter the found files (see `man find` to list them), including a `-name` option to filter on the file name. Use it as such:

```
$ find $yourdirectory -name MyMissingFile
```

which will match files whose names are exactly "MyMissingFile". To match names that contain "MyMissingFile", use:

```
$ find $yourdirectory -name "*MyMissingFile*"
```

Note that `locate` is usually much faster than `find`, since it has the answers in cache, while `find` needs to read all the files under the given directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
locate -r '/MyMissingFile$'
```

is more efficient than the suggestions using grep.    But not every version of locate accepts -r (though the locate in GNU findutils does).